# Matplotlib concentric shading (bullseye) in scatter plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to create a simple scatter plot. For this specific purpose, I would like to concentric circles around the origin with different colors (like a bullseye with 3 regions). I wonder, if there is something similar to `axvspan` and `axhspan` but for concentric shading?

Let me give you an example:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = x = np.linspace(0, 20, 50)
y = np.cos(3*x)


a = 3       # radius 0 to >a
b = 5       # radius a to >b    
c = 7       # radius b to c

plt.axvspan(a, b, color='r', alpha = 0.5)
plt.axhspan(a, b, color='y', alpha = 0.5)
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Instead of the horizontal and vertical shading, I want concentric green shading with a radius `a` from the origin, yellow from `a` to `b`, and red from `b` to `c`. Any ideas?

Comment: try with my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 50)
y = np.cos(3*x)

a = 3       # radius 0 to >a
b = 5       # radius a to >b
c = 7       # radius b to c


circle1 = plt.Circle((0, 0), a, color='green', alpha=0.3)
circle2 = plt.Circle((0, 0), b, color='yellow', alpha=0.3)
circle3 = plt.Circle((0, 0), c, color='red', alpha=0.3)

ax.add_artist(circle3)
ax.add_artist(circle2)
ax.add_artist(circle1)

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.axis([-22, 22, -22, 22])

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Great solution! Thank you! How can I decide to plot the scatter over the circles? Plus: Is it possible to use ellipses too?

Comment: @Rachel If I gave you my answer, mark it as correct.

Comment: Sorry. It did now. Though I don't think the solution is entirely correct, as the circles are above the scatter - and that's not a bullseye chart.